# Picasso loads the first uploaded image with the same name but browsers load the next

Tags: php, android

I upload images with the same name and extension
When the image is in existence in the upload destination folder , I unlink it firstand then move the file with the same name

chmod($Upload_path,0755) returns true ,
unlink($Upload_path) returns true
and move_uploaded_file returns true too

The problem is when I try to download the file:

1 - In Chrome and Firefox browsers the true image is downloaded but after a 
    while (Maybe 5 seconds or more), why after a while?!

> Edit: Some times after 20 seconds the newly updated image is loaded in
>   chrome and sometimes after 45 seconds

2 - In Android program, utilizing Picasso , the previous image is still 
    downloaded
    While to make sure that the previous image is really downloaded instead of 
    the new uploaded image with the same name (and it has nothing to do with 
    cache of picasso) :
    A - I delete cache of Picasso
    B - Utilize another clean mobile phone
    C - Make memory and network policy of picasso so as not to use cache
`.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE,NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)`

So why Picasso still downloads the previous image while browsers not ?!

3 - In server side I use Core FTP LE to verify the files
    When I click on the uploaded file, a message is exhibited that indicates the 
    folder already contains a file named ... (which is the name of the uploaded 
    file)
    When I unlinked the file and there is no sign of it there , what the hell is 
    this message?
How can I totally remove the previous file ?

Thanks In Advance

Edit:
PHP code:

```
        if(file_exists($Upload_path)) 
        {
            echo "\nPresent File Should Be Deleted";
            if (chmod($Upload_path,0755) === true)// Change the file permissions if allowed
            {
               echo "\nchmod true";
            }
            else
            {
               echo "\nchmod false";
            }

            if(unlink($Upload_path) === true)// remove the file
            {
               echo "\nunlink true";
            }
            else
            {
               echo "\nunlink false";
            }

        }

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $Upload_path)) {
            echo "\nMove successful";
        } 
        else
        {
            echo "\nMove failed";
        }
```

Android Code:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);


            int length = fileInputStream.available();

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("BBBuploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                Log.e(TAG, "Complete ");
            }
```

Comment: To a specific folder to server through android program

Comment: I hope this will help: It's HTTP request through Android Program (I can send the code if need be) and the server is placed in germany, About other information on the server I can say it's linux based, what other info is needed I don't know but code on android and PHP code is ready to send here if need be

Comment: `I upload images to a php server on the internet. The server runs Linux.`. That is all we wanna know. That is how you could have started your post so we knew where it was all about. Please post php code in a code block.

Comment: I've already emitted !

Comment: Your Android code is not reading the php echo()s. So you do not know what happens. `and move_uploaded_file returns true too` ? How would you know?

Comment: yes I read it next, I thought that part of the code would be enough,You know as I described everything is ok and images are updated in the server but the strange issue is time out of the browsers to update and the picasso which does not get updated at all, Edit : I replaced Picasso with Glide and the problem still persists

Comment: It seems the server still has the previous image stored and Picasso reads that data while browsers read the newly updated data , For your information I utilize F5 botton and press it every 5 seconds to see if the new image is exhibited or the previous image is still there , sometimes after 45 second when I see the new image on the server I see it on the browsers

Comment: Another strange point is when I check the Android program the next day Picasso loads the true image (the newly updated image) too

Comment: The word `cache` has not past in this post.